# .range.Formula of a Concatenate() to a server path

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to fill in a cell with the =CONCATENATE() formula which gave me errors,

```
strformula = "=CONCATENATE("\\SERVER\PATH\DIR\";$A5;".pdf")"
```

I tried to fix this with the incode concatenate & method
but I somehow have an error with the Sub

> "Method or data member not found"

Any ideas?

```
Sub Fillcells()
   Dim pthstr As String 
   Dim strformula As String
      With sheetNAME
        pthstr = "\\SERVER\PATH\DIR"
        strformula = "=CONCATENATE(" & pthstr & ";$A5;\" \ .pdf \ ")"
        
        .Range("N5:N5").Formula = strformula
        '.Range("N5", "N" & GetLastRow(sheetNAME)).FillDown
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: When using Formulas in VBA, you need to use the English convention. So try `strformula = "=CONCATENATE(" & pthstr & ",$A5,\" &  ".pdf \ )"

Comment: @MG92 Would that not cause an issue with the region settings of excel?

Comment: Excel VBA "translates" Formulas written in VBA to your local setting... If you want to use the local settings in VBA you need to use `Range().LocalFormula` instead of `Range().Formula`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple issues with how you're handling your string text. I think this will work as a formula for you or at least allow you to avoid errors.

`strformula = "=CONCATENATE(""" & pthstr & """,$A5,""\ .pdf \ "")"`

Note that for quotes within the formula, you have to use 2x double quotes. And if this is the end of your quote, you;ll have THREE sets, followed by an & sign.

However, I'm not sure concatenate is really what you want. You might just consider typing `="\\SERVER\PATH\DIR\"&A5&".PDF"`

There's almost no reason one should ever use Concatenate when compared to alternative functions such as textjoin or Concat. [This article explains](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/concat-vs-concatenate/). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the helpfull tips. I have mashed to two up so that. '="\\SERVER\PATH\DIR\"&A5&".PDF"' goes into strformula ;-)